# retrieve individual JSON data returned by cURL

Tags: php, json, curl

I used cURL to get response of my request, the response given is in JSON format and everything works fine, but I want to get specific
data from the JSON response. When I echo the entire data, it looks like below

> HTTP/1.1 100 Continue HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) Date: Fri, 29 Jan 2016 10:54:22 GMT Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 379 Status: 200 OK Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * Set-Cookie: __bakery_session=BAh7BkkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFVEkDM2YWI0MWZm%0AZTBkZTEwYTBiOTBlZmU0MWFmYmU5ZTlhZmE5ZDE3NWFjNzg3ODY0MDYxZDgG%0AOwBG%0A--0f1dadab3b89c8d34eb184b42b0781ce12c8adf0; path=/; HttpOnly Set-Cookie: rack.session=BAh7BkkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFVEkiRWM0MWYwOWNiNTYyODM2YWI0MWZm%0AZTBkZTEwYTBiOTBlZmU0MWFmYmU5ZTlhZmE5ZDE3NWFjNzg3ODY0MDYxZDgG%0AOwBG%0A; path=/; HttpOnly X-Served-By: bakery-breadroute-biscuit,bakery-prime-jubilee {"id":17772310,"name":"phpkAuyKh","type":"Image","created":"2016-01-29T10:54:22+00:00","updated":"2016-01-29T10:54:22+00:00","hashed_id":"enekkvawvr","description":"","progress":0.0,"status":"queued","thumbnail":{"url":"https://embed-ssl.wistia.com/deliveries/a70e7f7975ecb5f2bbf7b22e59f5d4d1112a4974.jpg?image_crop_resized=200x120","width":200,"height":120},"account_id":409257}

And my code is:

```
<?php       

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$url = "https://upload.wistia.com/?access_token=38316d1a944b503fc4408e0325daf2ceb3b58558238aab8d87c7cb6e2de2360b&project_id=8mtrjz3g8l";
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filedata = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
//$filesize = $_FILES['photo']['size'];
if ($filedata != '')
{
$headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"); // cURL headers for file uploading
$postfields = array("filedata" => "@$filedata", "filename" => $filename);
$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
//CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => $filesize,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
); // cURL options
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);

echo $result."<br />";
echo '<br><br><br>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<br>';
//echo json_decode($result, TRUE);

//echo curl_error($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

}

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Livehacks.tv</title>
<META CHARSET="UTF-8">
<META lang="en">
<META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<META name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">            
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>   
<div class="left_signup_container">
<form name="wistia" method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="videoForm">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" id="submit" value="upload">
</form>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

It prints the response, but I tried to retrieve only the ID from the data it returns using the below code, but not working

```
json_decode($result, TRUE);
$id = $result->id;
echo $id;
```

Any suggestions about how can I retrieve individual data in the JSON array..!!

Comment: $response = json_decode($result, TRUE);
$data['id'] = array();
$data['id'] = $response['id'];
echo $data['id'];

Comment: i tried your solution and echo $data['id'] , but it does not display the id

Comment: Your `$result` has a lot more than just a JSON string in it and therefore is not a valid JSON String

Comment: Sorry yes, i made a mistake as well. Will work like this:

$response = json_decode(@file_get_contents($urlForJSON), TRUE);
$data['id] = array();
$data['id'] = $response['id'];
echo $data['id'];

I did get the correct id from the echo when testing with your JSON. But keep in mind i had to modify the JSON removing it's header part as it won't work with it included.

Comment: should I replace $urlForJSON..???

Comment: Yes, this should be replaced with the URL you are getting the response from.

Answer (score 0):

As your returned data appears to be more than just a JSON String, amend your code to add some error checking.

Also you are trying to address `id` using the object notation, which is great, so dont bother converting your JSON String to an array using the `,TRUE` parameter.

```
json_decode($result);

if ( json_last_error() > 0 ) {
   echo json_last_error_msg();
   exit;
}

echo $result->id;
```